# Azure App Gateway WAF in front of Traefik Ingress on AKS

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, traefik-ingress, web-application-firewall

I am using Traefik ingress controller on AKS. I need to use WAF in front of it. As I found Azure application Gateway with WAF functionality can be used for that.

I have a DNS that points to Traefik ingress public IP. In order to connect Traefik to App GW WAF, I have added the DNS as a Host to HTTP Settings of Azure Application Gateway.
The healthprob is working fine. However I don't see any relevant WAF logs.

> AzureDiagnostics | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK" and
> Category == "ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog"

How can I test if App gateway WAF is working fine with Traefik ingress?

I'm wondering if I'm missing some setups here?

Comment: Hello @Matrix, May I know , if the diagnostics logging is enabled in the application gateway. Please refer : [Enable logging through the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics#enable-logging-through-the-azure-portal)

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. When I run that query, I see some logs with hostname that refers to Application Gateway public IP not logs related to Traefik ingress.